# Angular 2 App Deploy Size Reduction

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Below is a snapshot of my web app's network network tab that was built using Angular 2 and Angular CLI. I have cleaned the cache beforehand. As you can see, my largest file is 5.4mb which is the vendor.bundle.js file. Is that normal or is this file huge?!.

I am using the latest Angular CLI that utilizes AOT and TreeShaking. I have also implemented lazy loading so that only relevant components are loaded.

I followed firebase's guide to deploy my dist folder generated by ng build --prod to their hosting service using firebase deploy command in my terminal.

How can I further reduce the size or investigate which 'part' of my app is getting loaded that causes this size?

I have also found that when I use my mobile to load, it uses 2.2mb instead of the max size shown on my desktop which is 7.5mb. Is that normal?

[image: screenshot]

This is what I get for running ng--version

```
    node: 6.9.1
os: darwin x64
@angular/common: 2.4.9
@angular/compiler: 2.4.9
@angular/core: 2.4.9
@angular/forms: 2.4.9
@angular/http: 2.4.9
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.2
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.9
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.9
@angular/router: 3.4.9
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.9
```

My Dist Folder is shown in the image below. Funny thing as well, there is no vendor.bundle.js that was shown in the network tab. Is it because firebase takes vendor.2ff9250938e6ffbe8462.bundle and 'unzip?' it to vendor.bundle.js (which went from 1.4mb to 5.4mb. or am I talking fairy tale here?)

[image: Dist Folder]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are using --prod, if you were, it would show a random hash after your bundle files (unless I'm missing something, is there a way to disable it?).

[image]

And here is how it should look in chrome once gzip is applied:

[image]

Angular 4 will be soon available and reduces the total app size by about 25%.

---

Also I might be wrong but it looks like your images are too heavy, you should try to compress them a bit. A 5% compression can sometimes save more 50% of the size of the image.

Comment: Now you pointed out something interesting. I have included a screen shot of my dist folder and I do indeed have vendor.2ff9250938e6ffbe8462.bundle.js file. However, the network tab said I loaded a 5.4mb vendor.bundle.js file which does not exist in my dist folder at all?!

Comment: You probably did not push the correct version of your app to firebase, your bundles should show with a hash string in chrome. Add something in your app somewhere such as an app version number to make sure that the latest version of the app is uploaded.

Comment: Hmmm.. I have no idea why it is doing that. I have deployed to firebase using the same method for 80+ times and all my small changed gets reflected when I open up the website. That means my proper files are being uploaded. So at this stage I am not sure where that vender.bundle.js (5.4mb) is coming from

Comment: Do you clear your 'public' folder of your firebase project before you upload ? Also you could try `npm update -g` to update the firebase tools. And also try recreating a new firebase project.

Comment: Problem solved!. I was looking at the network tab of the localhost. Silly me!. Thanks for pointing out the image size though.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)